# Show function g(x) is continous

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm not able to understand how to prove this theorem.

> Consider a continuous function, $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb R$. Using the definition of
>   continuity, show that the function $g(x) = f(3x)$ is also continuous.

Comment: since $x$ belongs to $R$ that implies $3x$ also belongs o $R$...Can u carry out from here...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** First, show that the map $p:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $p(x)=3x$ is continuous.

Then show that if $p:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are continuous, then $f\circ p:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous.

Comment: can you please elaborate more ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$, we show $g$ is continuous at $x = a$, i.e. $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a} g(x) = g(a)$. To this end, let $\epsilon > 0$ be "given", since $f$ is continuous at $a$, $\exists \delta > 0$ : $ 0 < |x-a| < \delta \to |f(x)-f(a)| < \epsilon$. Now Let $\delta' = \dfrac{\delta}{3}$, then if $|x-a| < \delta' \to |3x-3a| < 3\delta' = \delta \to |f(3x)-f(3a)| < \epsilon \to |g(x) - g(a)| < \epsilon \to g \text{ is continuous at $x = a$}$